# Lazy tree loading in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to implement lazy tree loading in WPF. I have a `TreeView` which I populate with some nodes. Each node has a subnode with a "Loading..." header. What I want to achieve is:

1. User expands top node.
2. Top node expands and shows the "Loading..." subnode.
3. After the loading node is shown, method `foo` determines what subnodes to be added.
4. When the work is done, the "Loading..." node is removed and the new nodes which method `foo` has created are shown.

The idea is to send feedback to the user that the tree is loading since it takes quite some time for my `foo()` method to run.

The code which I have is this:

```
<TreeView x:Name="MyTree" TreeViewItem.Expanded="MyTreeItem_Expanded" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

private void MyTreeItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    // some logic to figure out from which node the event has been risen

    // method foo adds the new subnodes

    // code which removes the "Loading..." subnode
}
```

With this implementation, when I click on the node, the tree freezes and the node expands only after `foo()` is done and "Loading..." is removed.

How can I first show the "Loading..." node and then do the loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since everything is happening on the main ui thread items seems like the treeview is freezing. if possible process the foo on background worker.
below is modified sample from [wpf-tutorial.com](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/lazy-loading-treeview-items/) . This is not an optimized solution but will give you an idea.

```
      BackgroundWorker bgworker = new BackgroundWorker();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bgworker.DoWork += bgworker_DoWork;
        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo driveInfo in drives)
            trvStructure.Items.Add(CreateTreeItem(driveInfo));            
    }
    private void trvStructure_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = e.Source as TreeViewItem;
        bgworker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
    }
    void bgworker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {          
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)e.Argument;
        LoadFiles(item);           
    }
    void LoadFiles(TreeViewItem item)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        item.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<TreeViewItem>(AddItems), item);

    }      

    void AddItems(TreeViewItem item)
    {

        if ((item.Items.Count == 1) && (item.Items[0] is string))
        {
            item.Items.Clear();
            DirectoryInfo expandedDir = null;
            if (item.Tag is DriveInfo)
                expandedDir = (item.Tag as DriveInfo).RootDirectory;
            if (item.Tag is DirectoryInfo)
                expandedDir = (item.Tag as DirectoryInfo);
            try
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subDir in expandedDir.GetDirectories())
                {
                    item.Items.Add(CreateTreeItem(subDir));

                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

    }
    private TreeViewItem CreateTreeItem(object o)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
        item.Header = o.ToString();
        item.Tag = o;
        item.Items.Add("Loading...");
        return item;
    }
```

in `LoadFiles(TreeViewItem item)`  **`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);`** is giving UI time to expand.

Comment: I had tried with loading from another thread but it didn't work. The missing component was `Sleep(1000);` Thanks for helping!